# Is there a more flexible stock chart service, e.g. permitting choice of colours when comparing multiple stocks?

Tags: stocks, online-tools, online-data-source, comparison, chart

I'm regardful that these websites can concurrently exhibit the price history/graph/chart for several stocks:

- http://www.marketwatch.com/investing/fund/qqq
- http://biz.yahoo.com/charts/guide8.html
- http://money.msn.com/investing/stock-chart-information.aspx
- http://www.amcharts.com/stock-chart/
- https://www.google.com/finance

Nonetheless, they do not appear to allow changes to certain aspects of the chart, such as the colour delineating each stock.

For example, when these websites choose two similar colours for two different stocks, I'd like the ability to select more (discordant) colours.

Are there more efficient, powerful tools for this purpose?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there are any web based tools that would allow you to do this. The efforts required to build vs the perceived benefit to users is less. All the web providers want the data display as simple as possible; giving more features at times confuses the average user.